# Route-specific Middlewares with Negroni

Tags: web, go, middleware

I have a web server using httprouter and negroni. Users log into this system through external OAuth. We save the token to the encrypted session which indicates whether or not they are logged in. I would like to use a middleware to verify whether or not this token exists, and then kick the user back to the login page if it does not. I want to exclude some routes from using the authentication middleware. There is an example in the negroni README of doing this with gorilla mux, but I can't quite get my head around doing this scalably with httprouter. Something similar to my server setup is below:

```
router := httprouter.New()
router.GET("/login", Login) // auth not required
router.GET("/", Index)  // auth required

s := negroni.Classic()

s.Use(sessions.Sessions("example-web-dev", cookiestore.New([]byte("some garbage"))))
s.Use(authenticator.Get())
s.UseHandler(router)
```

Where `/login` is a route I do not want to require authorization through the middleware and `/` is. `authenticator.Get()` is my authentication handler func with contents I don't think are relevant to the question.

How can I apply `authenticator.Get()` to `/` but not `/login`? Keeping in mind that there will be several other "public" routes alongside `/login` and many other gated routes as well.

Some links:

- https://github.com/codegangsta/negroni
- https://github.com/codegangsta/negroni/issues/25
- http://godoc.org/github.com/codegangsta/negroni
- http://godoc.org/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was eventually able to wrap my brain around this process. The solution is to create new negroni.Negroni instances for each individual route. In the case above:

```
router := httprouter.New()
router.Handler("GET", "/login",
               negroni.New(negroni.HandlerFunc(loginHandler)))
router.Handler("GET", "/",
               negroni.New(authenticator.Get(),
               negroni.HandlerFunc(indexHandler)))

server := negroni.Classic()
server.UseHandler(router)
server.Use(sessions.Sessions("example-web-dev",
           cookiestore.New([]byte("some secret"))))
server.Run(":3000")
```

`loginHandler` and `indexHandler` will both need to have this method signature:

```
func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, http.HandlerFunc)
```

With the given example, all routes will utilize the middleware provided by `negroni.Classic()` and the `sessions` middleware added to `server`, but only `/` will use the middleware I created in `authenticator.Get()`.

Comment: However you don't have access to the `httprouter.Params` object in your handler functions anymore. Have you found a way to still access those?

Comment: @Tharsan - Unfortunately, I was never able to get access to the `httprouter.Params`. My current workaround is to parse the information I need from the URL, which is kind of terrible but functional.

Answer (score -1):

if using httprouter, params can be retrieved by calling the router.Lookup function. Here is what I did:

```
_, params, _ :=  router.Lookup("GET", req.URL.Path)
```

where router is an instance of `httprouter.Router`