# Negroni Route Specific Middleware

Tags: go, negroni

I'm struggling to get my route specific middleware working with httprouter and Negroni. The login route requires `Middleware2` and all the other routes require `Middleware1`.

So far I have:

```
func Main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    protectedRoutes := httprouter.New()

    DefineRoutes(router)
    DefineProtectedRoutes(protectedRoutes)

    //This is the block that I'm unsure about
    //How can I introduce Middleware2 for a specific route?
    n := negroni.New()
    n.Use(negroni.HandlerFunc(Middleware1))
    n.UseHandler(router)


    n.Run(":5000")
}

func DefineRoutes(router *httprouter.Router) {
    router.POST("/v1/users/authenticate", UserLogin)
    router.POST("/v1/users/authorize", UserLogin)
    router.POST("/v1/users/logout", UserLogout)
}

func DefineProtectedRoutes(router *httprouter.Router) {
    router.POST("/v1/users/login", UserLogin)
}
```

but now I'm a bit stuck as the examples on the site (https://github.com/codegangsta/negroni) use the standard handlers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Route-specific Middlewares with Negroni](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418168/route-specific-middlewares-with-negroni)

Comment: that answer covers it pretty well, basically you add a negroni middleware chain as a router handler. The down side is that you lose direct access to the `httprouter.Params`

Comment: I did see this one but as it was the same person answering his own question I wasn't convinced it was "the way to do it"

Comment: I couldn't find a better way to do it myself. It seems legit, although with that caveat I mentioned.

Comment: BTW I ended up manually copying data from the request params to the post params so that the handlers can still access it.

Comment: How did you manage to copy the request params over so the middleware handlers had access? Do you happen to have a gist somewhere I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone is still looking for an answer. I think params can be retrieved by calling the router.Lookup function. Here is what I did:

```
_, params, _ :=  router.Lookup("GET", req.URL.Path)
```

where router is an instance of httprouter.Router