# Different middleware for different routes in negroni

Tags: go, middleware, negroni

I want to have different middleware for different path. My current implementation is from this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/negroni-users/guXGTNGGLRU)

```
UserRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
AdminRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

Router.HandleFunc("/apps/{app_name}/xyz", Handler).Methods("GET")
```

I created three different routers, so that I can assosiate them with different path and middleware

```
nUserPath := negroni.New(middleware.NewAuthMiddleWare())
nUserPath.UseHandler(UserRouter)

nAdminPath := negroni.New()
nAdminPath.UseHandler(AdminRouter)
```

I created two different negroni instances and passed them the respective routers. As I wanted all this to run part of the same application on the same port so I created a Wrapper Router and negroni instance and associated them with the existing like below

```
BaseRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
BaseRouter.Handle(UserBasePath,nUserPath) // UserBasePath is `/apps`
BaseRouter.Handle(HealthCheck,nUserPath)  // HealthCheck is `/health`
BaseRouter.Handle(AdminBasePath,nAdminPath) // AdminBasePath is `/Admin`

n := negroni.New(middleware.NewLogger()) // attached other common middleware here
n.UseHandler(router.BaseRouter)
n.Run(":8080")
```

Issues faced in this approach:
When I run `/health` it runs properly but when I run `/apps/{app_name}/something` I get a `404: Not Found`

Note : I went through other approaches mentioned in below link but they don't satisfy my need.

### - [Route-specific Middlewares with Negroni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418168/route-specific-middlewares-with-negroni)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue with the above implementation is that BaseRouter.Handle() method take a **path** and not a **path_matcher/template** so all the url's which has path_length more than one were not working.

I figured out two ways to achieve what I needed:
***First approach***

```
// Create a rootRouter
var rootRouter *mux.Router = mux.NewRouter()

// Create as many subRouter you want with some prefix
var appsBasePath string = "/apps"
var adminBasePath string = "/admin"
upRouter := rootRouter.PathPrefix(appsBasePath).Subrouter()
apRouter := rootRouter.PathPrefix(adminBasePath).Subrouter()

// Register all the paths and mention middleware specifically for all of them
// Here middleware is a method with signature as
// func middleware( http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {}

upRouter.Path("/test").Methods("POST").Handler(middleware(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the home page!")
})))

n := negroni.New(middleware.NewLogger()) // attached other common middleware here
n.UseHandler(rootRouter)
n.Run(":8080")
```

***Second approach***
This is extension/solution of the original issue in the question

```
// Replace BaseRouter.handle() as below
// as PathPrefix takes a template so it won't have issue that we were facing  

BaseRouter.PathPrefix(UserBasePath).Handler(nUserPath)
```

Thing to remember here is that within negroni `nUserPath` RequestContext of the middleware attached will be different from that of the actual router's HandlerMethod

Note:
By path length I mean something like this -- /abc or /abc/ has path_length=1 and /abc/xyz has path_length=2